# Accesing already created Sqlite database through phonegap

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, html, cordova

I have just started using phonegap, and my application demands an use of a database for storage. Now, i have read all the documentation for phone-gap's storage, but nowhere is it given that one can access an already present database.
My question is that can one use an already created database through phonegap? if so then how to do it? where and how to include the database file and how to retrieve values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily.

There are some seemingly hackish ways to do it, but I have nto tested them. I will post links below.

I am in the same boat. Here is what I am planning (I have done this before with AIR applications for different reasons, I will be doing it with my next PhoneGap app).

Using a tool like SQLite Studio I will take the pre-existing DB and export it (data and all) to a create script. Then I will use that create script to create and load the DB and tables the first time the app runs. Unless you are dealign with a huge amount of data I think this would work in most cases.

References for the hacky solutions:

http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/ca6c85f7d6c3976c/1195990551444915
http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/5e57a728dc66a2a1

Comment: i saw that article, and what you are planning to do seems that it could make it work. The deal is, that my PM wants me to create an app that'll work on IOS and ANDROID, so the way that is used in the link you mentioned explicitly uses objective-C and also the path's that the databases are going to be stored in their respective emulators is gonna be different. So i guess it won't work on ANDROID, or else what i'll have to do is that i'll have to find a similar workaround for android and write a script for it as well.

Comment: Your way of doing it seems more sensible, thanks for sharing it :)