# How to retrieve value from existing database using phonegap in android

Tags: android, cordova, sqlite

i need to retrieve value from existing database through phonegap.How to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709134/accesing-already-created-sqlite-database-through-phonegap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.Here is the link [phonegap wiki link](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494756/Adding%20SQL%20Database%20support%20to%20your%20iPhone%20App) 
This shows how we can access the database.